# GUI program terminates without display

Tags: java, user-interface, checkbox, checkboxlist

I'm trying to write a GUI application that displays the total for a customer's visit to Joe's automotive center. I'm using checkboxes for clicking on the service and that being add to the total for the customer. My program runs and terminates quickly, nothing pops up.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;

import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;



public class JoesAuto extends JPanel{

    private JTextField tOilchangeBox;
    private JTextField tLubeJob;
    private JTextField tRadiatorFlush;
    private JTextField tTransmissionFlush;
    private JTextField tInspection;
    private JTextField tMufflerReplacement;
    private JTextField tTireRotation; 

    private JCheckBox oilchangeBox;
    private JCheckBox lubeJob;
    private JCheckBox radiatorFlush;
    private JCheckBox transmissionFlush;
    private JCheckBox inspection;
    private JCheckBox mufflerReplacement;
    private JCheckBox tireRotation;





    public final double OIL_CHANGE_BOX = 26;
    public final double LUBE_JOB = 18;
    public final double RADIATOR_FLUSH = 30;
    public final double TRANSMISSION_FLUSH = 80;
    public final double INSPECTION = 15;
    public final double MUFFLER_REPLACEMENT = 100;
    public final double TIRE_ROTATION = 20;



    //CONSTRUCTOR

    public JoesAuto()
    {

        setLayout(new GridLayout(7,1));

        oilchangeBox = new JCheckBox ("Oil Change Box");
        lubeJob = new JCheckBox ("Lube Job");
        radiatorFlush= new JCheckBox ("Radiator Flush");
        transmissionFlush = new JCheckBox ("Transmission Flush");
        inspection = new JCheckBox ("Inspection");
        mufflerReplacement = new JCheckBox ("Muffler Replacement");
        tireRotation = new JCheckBox ("Tire Rotation");

        //add a border around the panel 
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Services"));

        //add checkboxes to the panel 

        add(oilchangeBox);
        add(lubeJob);
        add(radiatorFlush);
        add(transmissionFlush);
        add(inspection);
        add(mufflerReplacement);
        add(tireRotation);
    }

        //get method returns the cost of selected services 

        public double getServiceCost()
        {
        double serviceCost = 0.0;

        if(oilchangeBox.isSelected())
            serviceCost += OIL_CHANGE_BOX;
        if(lubeJob.isSelected())
            serviceCost += LUBE_JOB;
        if(radiatorFlush.isSelected())
            serviceCost += RADIATOR_FLUSH;
        if(transmissionFlush.isSelected())
            serviceCost += TRANSMISSION_FLUSH;
        if(inspection.isSelected())
            serviceCost += INSPECTION;
        if(mufflerReplacement.isSelected())
            serviceCost += MUFFLER_REPLACEMENT;
        if(tireRotation.isSelected())
            serviceCost += TIRE_ROTATION;

        return serviceCost;

        }

        public static void main(String args[])
        {
            new JoesAuto();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What you have so far is a `JPanel`, you will need to add this panel to a frame and display that frame.

Comment: How do I add this to a frame? Can you point me to a website?

Comment: how come my total cost isn't popping up?

Answer (score 0):

What you have so far is a `JPanel`, you will need to add this panel to a frame and display that frame.

Here is an example:

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    JFrame frame = new JFrame(); // create a new frame
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); //terminate the program when this frame is closed
    frame.add(new JoesAuto()); // add the panel to the frame
    frame.pack(); // resize the frame to fit all the components
    frame.setVisible(true); // show the frame
}
```

Comment: @sam It should be inside the body of a class. You should replace the `main(...)` method that you already have with this one.

Comment: I did that and it still didn't run

Comment: @sam I've just tested this and it works. Can you edit your question to reflect the changes that you've made ?

Comment: below is what I have so far

Comment: @sam is not calculating the `serviceCost` because you never call the `getServiceCost()` method, you should add a button to this panel and call the method when the button is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

@titus this is what I have so far, and it does work, how come it's not calculating the checkboxes that I've chosen

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;

import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;



public class JoesAuto extends JPanel{

private JTextField tOilchangeBox;
private JTextField tLubeJob;
private JTextField tRadiatorFlush;
private JTextField tTransmissionFlush;
private JTextField tInspection;
private JTextField tMufflerReplacement;
private JTextField tTireRotation; 

private JCheckBox oilchangeBox;
private JCheckBox lubeJob;
private JCheckBox radiatorFlush;
private JCheckBox transmissionFlush;
private JCheckBox inspection;
private JCheckBox mufflerReplacement;
private JCheckBox tireRotation;





public final double OIL_CHANGE_BOX = 26;
public final double LUBE_JOB = 18;
public final double RADIATOR_FLUSH = 30;
public final double TRANSMISSION_FLUSH = 80;
public final double INSPECTION = 15;
public final double MUFFLER_REPLACEMENT = 100;
public final double TIRE_ROTATION = 20;



//CONSTRUCTOR

public JoesAuto()
{

    setLayout(new GridLayout(7,1));

    oilchangeBox = new JCheckBox ("Oil Change Box");
    lubeJob = new JCheckBox ("Lube Job");
    radiatorFlush= new JCheckBox ("Radiator Flush");
    transmissionFlush = new JCheckBox ("Transmission Flush");
    inspection = new JCheckBox ("Inspection");
    mufflerReplacement = new JCheckBox ("Muffler Replacement");
    tireRotation = new JCheckBox ("Tire Rotation");

    //add a border around the panel 
    setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Services"));

    //add checkboxes to the panel 

    add(oilchangeBox);
    add(lubeJob);
    add(radiatorFlush);
    add(transmissionFlush);
    add(inspection);
    add(mufflerReplacement);
    add(tireRotation);
}

    //get method returns the cost of selected services 

    public double getServiceCost()
    {
    double serviceCost = 0.0;

    if(oilchangeBox.isSelected())
        serviceCost += OIL_CHANGE_BOX;
    if(lubeJob.isSelected())
        serviceCost += LUBE_JOB;
    if(radiatorFlush.isSelected())
        serviceCost += RADIATOR_FLUSH;
    if(transmissionFlush.isSelected())
        serviceCost += TRANSMISSION_FLUSH;
    if(inspection.isSelected())
        serviceCost += INSPECTION;
    if(mufflerReplacement.isSelected())
        serviceCost += MUFFLER_REPLACEMENT;
    if(tireRotation.isSelected())
        serviceCost += TIRE_ROTATION;

    return serviceCost;

    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame(); // create a new frame
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); //terminate the program when this frame is closed
        frame.add(new JoesAuto()); // add the panel to the frame
        frame.pack(); // resize the frame to fit all the components
        frame.setVisible(true); // show the frame
    }
}
```